# Excel, sum range split

Tags: google-docs

I have a google spreadsheet and I want calculate to some data...

I want to sum the splits in a range

```
 1 |    A1     |   
 2 |    1Q1    |    
 3 |    3Q2    |   
 4 |    5Q7    |
```

I need the sum of the integers after the letter "Q" so in the example above I would get `1+2+7=10`

Comment: In column `B1` enter `=RIGHT(A1,1)`, drag this down, then sum up the results.

Comment: I and what if the number is more than 1 digit Jason?

Comment: is this Excel, or Google-docs spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

This formula will do it all in one,   just set the range in the formula , ie A2:A4

```
 =SUM(VALUE((RIGHT(A2:A4,LEN(A2:A4)-FIND("Q",A2:A4,1)))))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter the array formula.

Comment: I'd suggest: `=VALUE(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND("Q",A:A,1)))` as you need it converted to a numeric value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `VALUE(RIGHT(text))` which will give you back the number value of the rightmost character in the string.  Then use those values in your sum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 3rd character is the number, you could try something like

```
=VALUE(MID(A:A,3,len(A:A)))
```

in column B

then sum that like this (for the 1st 3 rows):

```
=SUM(B1:B3)
```